# Excel macro that inserts new row (including automatic row numbering and dropdown list) in protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an excel macro that inserts a new row (including automatic row numbering in column A) in my table. Some of the columns contain dropdown lists so my new row also needs to have the same dropdown lists.

But when I enable worksheet protection, the automatic numbering doesn't work well anymore. The new row just becomes a duplicate with number 2 in the first column (so now I have multiple rows with number 2 instead of a new row with a new number). Is there anybody that can help me out?

I have used the following code which does what I want when the worksheet isn't protected:

```
Sub Button01()
Range("A8").EntireRow.Insert
Range("A8") = 1
Range("A8:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).DataSeries , xlDataSeriesLinear
End Sub
```

Unfortunately the problem arises when the worksheet is protected.

Comment: You should try unprotecting the sheet in your code before you add the new row, then re-protect when done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need the worksheet protected as the user of the button that runs the macro should be allowed to insert a row but should not be allowed to edit other parts of the work sheet. Is there a way I can add unprotecting the sheet and re-protecting it automatically as a macro?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42212517/478884